# Что лучше выбрать для хранения enum или integer?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb

Очень часто появляется задача хранить какие то данные типа:

```
Колонка пол: мужской, женский.
Колонка ваше образование: Экономист, Психолог, Юрист.
Колонка категории товаров: Стулья, Столы, Шкафы, Кровати, Диваны.
```

Удобство со стороны исходного кода не рассматривается и не интересует. Вопрос чисто организации базы данных, а также хранения такого типа данных.

---

## UPD.

Вопрос состоит не в том, как организовать хранение данных помимо enum или integer (то что вы начали предлагать справочники, либо булево значения). Вопрос заключается в том, как хранить такие данные которые попадают под enum определение в enum или integer (повторюсь не в булево, не в справочниках, ни каким либо другим способом, а именно одним из тех что я перечислил). Возможно я не совсем корректные примеры привёл, которые сбили вас с толку.

Вот другие примеры:

```
1. Какие магазины вы посещаете чаще всего: Супермаркет, Мегамаркет, Гипермаркет, обычный магазин, киоск, рынок.
2. Какой у вас рост: низкий, средний, высокий, огромный
3. Какой у вас размер одежды: M, S, L, XL, XXL, XXXL
```

В приведенных выше примерах не вижу смысл делать справочники.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Колонка пол: мужской, женский.

Вообще флаги (колонки со значениями `да/нет`), конечно, удобней хранить в `boolean` (1/0).
Но конкретно колонку "пол" я бы хранил в `char(1)`. Особенно если поле обязательно для заполнения. Системных ресурсов `char(1)` сожрет не намного больше, чем `boolean`, зато чисто организационно для любого вида отчетов проще: на экран выходит `М/Ж`, а не `1/0`, которые потом еще как-то в те же `М/Ж` переводить все равно надо...
Еще раз: это только конкретно для колонки "пол".

> Колонка ваше образование: Экономист, Психолог, Юрист.
>   Колонка категории товаров: Стулья, Столы, Шкафы, Кровати, Диваны.

Тут я соглашусь с вариантом №1 от @Suvitruf: использовать справочники. Отдельные таблицы-справочники с вариантами значений, а в основной таблице хранить лишь `id` из соответствующего справочника.
Тут много преимуществ:

1. редактирование: если значение меняется - меняешь лишь в одном месте
2. организация: если важна очередность этих самых значений между собой, то можно (нужно) хранить порядковый номер в очереди в этом справочнике
3. организация (2): если есть какие-то аттрибуты, присущие каждому значению - можно же хранить в той же таблице-справочнике, не трогая основную
4. многоязычность: если Ваш проект на нескольких языках, то в справочнике Вы храните все варианты, и добавление еще одного языка для Вас не составит проблем

*Еще.*
Если у Вас есть сразу несколько полей, для которых можно использовать таблицы-справочники, и варианты в этих справочниках будут представлять из себя лишь текст без каких-либо аттрибутов (см. пункты 1-3 из списка выше), то можно организовать одну таблицу-справочник на несколько колонок.

Т.е. создается таблица такого типа:

```
id [int] PK
attribute [enum(education, category)]
value varchar(32)
```

В нее заносятся все данные:

```
id| attribute | value
----------------------
1 | education | Экономист
2 | education | Психолог
3 | education | Юрист
4 | category  | Стулья
5 | category  | Столы
6 | category  | Шкафы
7 | category  | Кровати
8 | category  | Диваны
```

И уже `id` этой одной таблицы заносятся в основную.
Строго говоря даже здесь можно организовать очередность (пункт 2 из списка выше), но это уже детали.

---

---

**UPDATE**

> 1. Какие магазины вы посещаете чаще всего: Супермаркет, Мегамаркет, Гипермаркет, обычный магазин, киоск, рынок.
> 2. Какой у вас рост: низкий, средний, высокий, огромный
> 3. Какой у вас размер одежды: M, S, L, XL, XXL, XXXL
>
> В приведенных выше примерах не вижу смысл делать справочники.

Ну если у Вас фиксированный набор значений, и этот набор меняться не будет, то, думаю, хранить в `enum` проще.
Более того, `enum` занимает 1 или 2 байта (в зависимости от кол-ва значений), а `int`- аж целых 4 байта :)

Вобщем мой ответ: `enum`

Comment: обнови вопрос (15 букаф)

Comment: Спасибо! Получается на одно значение enum хранит от 1 или 2 байта, и если их скажем 6 значений то будет до 10 байт занимать место. Получается enum уже не выгодно, так как int занимает 4 байта?

Comment: @vladik, нет-нет, вы не поняли... `int` тогда будет не 4 байта, а 24 :) Видимо Вы не совсем поняли - MySQL хранит  поле `enum` как таблицу-справочник :) Только это на уровне системных каких-то скрытых таблиц. Понимаете? Вот док, объясняющий, сколько каждый тип полей занимает места: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Пол - можно `bool`'ом. В MySQL для этого `BOOL`/`BOOLEAN`, тот же `TINYINT(1)`.

По поводу же двух других кейсов. Образование и товары же, по сути, [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)'ы. Но я обычно их не использую.
Вижу два варианта решения помимо enum'ов:

1. Вроде самый логичный вариант - использовать справочники. 
   Скажем, в случае с образованием, у вас будет таблица-справочник
   **Education**, в которой записи: Экономист, Психолог, Юрист и т.п. Тогда
   в таблице, где у вас в колонке необходимо образование, вы
   ссылается вторичным ключом на запись из первой таблицы. При таком
   варианте вы легко можете добавлять новые виды образования (или же
   товаров, если мы про них говорим), и т.д.
2. Свой enum хранить в базе:

Если у вас

```
enum Education{
    Экономист, 
    Психолог, 
    Юрист
}
```

а) В виде int'ов.
То при сохранении в базу `(int)Education.Экономист`

б) В виде строк.

При сохранении в базу `Education.Экономист.toString()`

В виде интов проще, меньше места, в общем очевидны плюшки. Проблемы
    начинаются, когда вы на клиенте enum измените (вставите что-то в
    середину, новый товар добавится), тогда порядок элементов поменяется. И всё
    медным тазов накроется.  Так что, в этом варианте я бы рекомендовал
    в виде строк.

Comment: Вариант 1 понятен. А вот насчет варианта 2. "enum хранить в базе" - Вы имеете ввиду так и хранить текстом? Т.е. иметь `varchar` поле куда и вписывать "Экономист", "Психолог", "Шкаф", "Стул".

Comment: Обновил ответ )

Comment: @cyadvert да, как varchar. Но, всё ж, рекомендую лучше доп. таблицу-справочник сделать

Comment: @Suvitruf Обновил свой вопрос

Comment: @Suvitruf согласен